# How do I redirect to all pages to be a subdirectory of another website but keep the URLs the same?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website that has been built at say `montypython.netlify.app`

The client has their main website at `holygrail.com` and they want `holygrail.com/resources` to show the contents of `montypython.netlify.app` but *keep the URL the same*. Which means that it should continue to show `holygrail.com/resources` in the search bar.

This also means that any pages from `montypython.netlify.app` should appear are subdirectories of `holygrail.com/resources`

Example:
`montypython.netlify.app/about` should appear as `holygrail.com/resources/about`

I am guessing this has to do with editing the .htaccess at `holygrail.com` but what rewrite/redirect rules can I reference? There are a lot of URLs so is there a wildcard approach I can use?

This is what I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^holygrail\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ https://montypython.netlify.app/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried .htaccess rules in your question, as its highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've added some rules

Comment: Thanks for doing so. IMHO I don't think that you can show other domain's contents without changing URL in browser.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I do this with two of my Netlify websites. The [Netlify TOML](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/website/blob/main/netlify.toml) shows the redirect rules. If you go to [this page](https://thedivtagguy/projects/food-apps), it is actually showing the contents of [this page](https://thedivtagguy.netlify.app/projects/food-apps/), so I do know it is possible but I don't know how to make this work with .htaccess

Comment: You would need to configure the source server as a _reverse proxy_. You can't do this in `.htaccess` alone, unless this has already been partly configured in the main server config and the necessary modules (mod_proxy etc) installed. Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: How did you configure this with Netlify? Ordinarily, you would point your domain at the external service and inform to service to accept requests at that domain (you can then implement internal rewrites if you need to - and if permited) then you don't have to mess with reverse proxies. Netlify docs - custom domain: https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/

Comment: @MrWhite Honestly, looking at how difficult this seems, I'm surprised I got this running at all. I referred to [these docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#app) and it just...worked? The rest is in my netlify.toml which I linked above, thats all there was to it. 

Could you clarify what 'source server' means? Would this be the server that is hosting `holygrail.com`? Could you also provide an example of what these rules would look like? I am a front-end dev so I'm massively out of my depth here, I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: When I go to https://thedivtagguy/projects/food-apps I get a dns not found error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[P]` proxy flag of `mod_rewrite`.

Using `[P]` flag instructs `mod_rewrite` to handle the request via `mod_proxy`. Therefore, you must enable `mod_proxy` to use flag.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^holygrail\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ https://montypython.netlify.app/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

with this code snippet, all pages to be a subdirectory `resources` will be served from `https://montypython.netlify.app/` without a 301 redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your issue is with the line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^holygrail\.com$ [NC]
```

Maybe you need to try to do something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ https://montypython.netlify.app/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on projects in the past with similar objectives. I don't believe you can accomplish this with redirects. The suggestion about using a reverse proxy would be the most well aligned with your requirements, but there is another option that may also be useful. Some DNS providers offer "DNS Cloaking" or "Stealth Redirects". This can be configured so that requests for `holygrail.com` will display a frame containing the content for `montypython.netlify.app`. Could you use the same approach for the `/resources` sub-directory, so that `holygrail.com/resources` delivers a frame that loads `montypython.netlify.app`?

The drawback to this is the address bar will not change as you navigate inside the frame, e.g. navigating to `montypython.netlify.app/resources/about` will still show `holygrail.com/resources` in the address bar, because it is displaying the address of the frame.